# Uploading images into a folder and insert record into SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, post

I want to upload multiple images in my folder and store them in my SQL database. But I can't seem to do it. When I run this code I'm not getting any errors or whatsoever. Did I miss something? Thank you for the help!

```html
<?php
include ("dbconnect.php");

if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++)
    {
        $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
        $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
        $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];
        $filepath = "photo/".$filename;
    
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO image (homeImage) VALUES ('$filename')";
    $result = mysql_query($con, $sql);
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple />
<input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Upload">    
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: does it save the images into the target directory?

Comment: You are **ignoring** any error that might occur. move_uploaded_file has a return value that tells you whether it succeeded or not … and how to check the same for your database query, please go _research_ that.

Comment: Incidentally the `mysql` api is deprecated and removed from php 7+...

Comment: @RamRaider It does not.

Comment: I'd suspect the target path might be the issue in that case assuming that this page above is `upload.php`

Comment: what is the error you got ?

Comment: @RamRaider hmm. I have a folder called `photo` in the same folder with my `upload.php` file as well as the same withe the `$filepath` idk. why

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I'm not getting any error. Idk why

Comment: I also changed `mysql` into `mysqli`. Still not working though

Comment: insert in database work correctly ? . anyway , can you add this **error_reporting(E_ALL);** at the top of your script , just after php tag . this will show if there is an error behind.

Comment: Add this to the top of you PHP page right under the opening PHP tag.  It will show any errors occurring on the screen for you.  Remove when ready for production.  `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the full path for the target directory - so if it is within the same directory as this script use `__DIR__` or `getcwd()`

Hopefully the below will help - worked in test for me just now

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['btn_upload'] ) ){

        include ("dbconnect.php");

        for( $i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file_img']['name']); $i++) {

            $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i];
            $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i];
            $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i];

            /* check target folder exists, create path if necessary */
            $targetdir = __DIR__ . '/photo/';
            if( !file_exists( $targetdir ) )mkdir( $targetdir, 0777, true );
            clearstatcache();

            $filepath = $targetdir . "/" . $filename;

            $status = move_uploaded_file( $filetmp, $filepath );
            if( $status ){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO image ( `homeImage` ) VALUES ('$filename')";

                $result = mysql_query( $con, $sql );
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>File Upload and store...</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='file_img[]' multiple />
            <input type='submit' name='btn_upload' value='Upload'>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```